# Rails/Grape NameError - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

In my Rails/Grape app I've got a service which is responsible for fetch name of model from DatoCMS. When I'm trying to call this service in the endpoint I'm getting an error:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant CmsApi
Did you mean?  CmsAPI:
```

Controller is defined and mounted well because only this new service didn't work.

`app/controllers/api/v1/webhook/cms/receive_webhook.rb`

```
module Cms
  class ReceiveWebhook < Base
    http_basic do |user, password|
      user == Rails.application.credentials.datocms_user &&
        password == Rails.application.credentials.datocms_password
    end

    post :datocms do
      ::CmsApi::FetchModelName.new('245466').call
    end
  end
end
```

`app/services/cms_api/fetch_model_name.rb`

```
module CmsApi
  class FetchModelName
    def initilizer(model_id)
      @model_id = model_id
    end

    def call
      fetch_model(model_id).dig('name')
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Dato::Site::Client.new(Rails.application.credentials.datocms_api_token)
    end

    def fetch_model(model_id)
      client.item_types.find(model_id)
    end
  end
end
```

As you see I didn't defined any `CmsAPI` which error mentioned. What did I've missed?

Comment: What happens if you try CmsAPI::FetchModelName? 

Does an error similar to 'expected app/services/cms_api/fetch_model_name.rb to define it' appear?

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: In which rails env does this occur? Can you show the relevant env files? Is auto loading working correctly for other components?

Comment: Ok I figured out! When I change `module CmsApi` to `module ReceiveWebhook`  (name of the controller) and do the same for the folder path to be `app/services/receive_webhook/fetch_model_name.rb` it works well. I'm not sure but maybe it's a Grape convention.